# AWK: Equal unique identifier using two file and count that match criteria

Tags: awk

I am working with two data that match the account number within two files.
And having a condition or criteria with the value from second file and count that match with the condition.

First file is fixed-length, the account number is from 1 to 8:

```
68541561        12531563     20211205154331……NN061
68541562        12531563     20211205154332……NN061
68541563        12531563     20211205154333……NN000
68541564        12531563     20211205154334……NN061
68541565        12531563     20211205154335……NN000
68541566        12531563     20211205154336……NN061
```

Second file is comma-delimited, the structure is like definition file but with duplicates records.

```
68541561,Customer Proc 1
68541565,Answer
68541561,Customer Proc 1
68541562,Customer Proc 1
68541561,Customer Proc 1
68541563,Answer
68541562,Customer Proc 1
68541564,Customer Proc 1
68541565,Answer 
68541564,Customer Proc 1
68541565,Answer
68541561,Customer Proc 1
68541562,Customer Proc 1
68541563,Answer
```

Expected Output, it will add the count from the first file:

```
68541561        12531563     20211205154331……NN0614
68541562        12531563     20211205154332……NN0613
68541563        12531563     20211205154333……NN0002
68541564        12531563     20211205154334……NN0612
68541565        12531563     20211205154335……NN0003
68541566        12531563     20211205154336……NN0610
```

I do have script that working on but it only display count 1, it seems it just read only the first file.

> awk -f test.awk pass=0 testfile2.dat pass=1 testfile.txt

```
BEGIN{
}
pass==0{
   ACT=substr($1)
   RES[ACT]=$2
}
pass==1{
   FS=","
   ACT=substr($0,1,8)
   
   ##LIST[ACT]=RESCODE
   LIST[ACT]=ACT
   
   if((RES[ACT]=="Customer Proc 1")){ OTHCUST1++ }
   if((RES[ACT]=="Customer Proc 2")){ OTHCUST2++ }
   if((RES[ACT]=="Customer Proc 3")){ OTHCUST3++ }
   if((RES[ACT]=="Customer Proc 4")){ OTHCUST4++ }
   if((RES[ACT]=="Answer")){  OTHANSW++ }
   if((RES[ACT]=="Busy")){ OTHBUSY++ }
   if((RES[ACT]=="Hang Up")){ OTHAM++ }
   
}
END{
   for (nmb in LIST) {
      printf "%1378s|", $0             >> "OUTFILE"
      printf "%s", OTHCUST1            >> "OUTFILE"
      printf "%s", OTHCUST2            >> "OUTFILE"
      printf "%s", OTHCUST3            >> "OUTFILE"
      printf "%s", OTHCUST4            >> "OUTFILE"
      printf "%s", OTHANSW             >> "OUTFILE"
      printf "%s", OTHBUSY             >> "OUTFILE"
      printf "%s", OTHAM               >> "OUTFILE"
   }
}
```

Comment: That script cannot be working as it has a syntax error at `substr($1)`. It also seems to be totally unrelated to the problem you describe. Finally - don't use all upper case variable names to avoid clashes with builtin variable names and to make your code clearer with respect to where it is/isn't using builtin variables.

Comment: You say `First file is fixed-length, the account number is from 1 to 8` but then you show sample input where the account number is always just the first space-separated field. If it ever is NOT just the first space-separated field then include examples of that in your input, otherwise the stuff about it being fixed width and the first 8 chars is just muddying the problem and leading to a more complicated solution than necessary (having to use `substr($0,1,8)` instead of just `$1`).

Comment: Got it. I just trying to port with my current awk script with the condition. But basically I can use different awk script to avoid complexity for this scenario.

Comment: When asking for help with a problem, though, you're supposed to create and post a [mcve] with sample code that concisely demonstrates **just that problem**, not throw up whatever code you have lying around as that's like asking your mechanic to fix your car but showing them your horse. See [ask].

Answer (score 4):

Your question isn't entirely clear but I THINK this is what you're trying to do:

```
$ awk -F'[,[:space:]]+' 'NR==FNR{cnt[$1]++; next} {print $0 cnt[$1]+0}' file2 file1
68541561        12531563     20211205154331……NN0614
68541562        12531563     20211205154332……NN0613
68541563        12531563     20211205154333……NN0002
68541564        12531563     20211205154334……NN0612
68541565        12531563     20211205154335……NN0003
68541566        12531563     20211205154336……NN0610
```

By the way, where you do `FS=","` in your posted code is too late - the first line of input has already been read and split into fields before that line is read. One way to get it do to what you want is change `FS=","` to `if (FNR==1) { FS=","; $0=$0 }` to get awk to re-split the record after setting FS but that's inefficient so I wrapped it in an `if` to only do that for the first line read as after that `FS` is now set before the 2nd and subsequent lines are read.

All those `printf "%s"`s in your code should be `printf "%d"`s btw otherwise you'll get null strings instead of zeros printed when the conditions that set the count variables aren't hit.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr[$1]++
  next
}
($1 in arr){
  print $0 arr[$1]
  delete arr[$1]
}
' FS="," file2 FS=" " file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                        ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                     ##Checking condition which will be TRUE when file2 is being read.
  arr[$1]++                  ##Creating array with name arr with index of $1.
  next                       ##next will skip statements from here.
}
($1 in arr){                 ##Checking condition if $1 is present in arr.
  print   $0 arr[$1]         ##printing current line here with arr[$1].
  delete arr[$1]             ##Deleting arr entry with $1 here.
}
' FS="," file2 FS=" " file1  ##Set FS as comma for file2 and space for file1 and pass Input_files too here.
```